# Related rate volume increasing

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find out how fast the water level is rising in a tub that is filling at a rate of $.7 \text{ft}^3 / \text{min}$

I am not too sure how to do this, I am given that the base of the bathtub is $18 \text{ft}^2$ and that it is rectangular.

I know that $$b * h = v$$ but I am not so sure how to use this.

I know that the derivitive of the volume is $.7$

and that the base is a constant so it goes to zero, that leaves me with

$$h = .7$$

So does that mean the height increases $.7$ feet a minute? That is the wrong answer but I don't see why. My logic seems correct and the formulas are right as well.

Comment: Hint : Take the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \text{area} \cdot \frac{dh}{dt}$$

Solve for $dh/dt$.

Comment: Why am I mutliplying by the derivative of height? I get that it is what I am trying to find but how does it fit in?

Comment: As I said in my solution, solve for $dh/dt$.  You are given the other information.  How did that coe about?  By taking the derivative of $V = \text{area} \cdot h$.

Comment: Area is a constant so wouldn't it go away when you take the derivative?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} [c f(x)] = c \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$$